# Fluent Query Builder Getting Bind Variables in Wrong Order?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, fluent

Been scratching my head over some queries not coming back with all the rows they should be, and I believe the reason is the bind variables not being ordered correctly. Is this a fluent bug, or am I doing something very wrong?

Here is an example, stripped down bare, to show what is happening. Query q1 selects from a table with a simple where condition. Query q2 joins to a table (kind of) with a condition in the ON statement. The main query q joins to a table with an arbitrary condition.

```
$q1 = DB::table('c')->where('d', '=', 'second');
$q2 = DB::table('e')->join('f', function($join){$join->where('f.id', '=', 'third');});
$q = DB::table('x')->join('y', function($join){$join->where('y.id', '=', 'first');})
    ->unionAll($q1) // binds to 'second'
    ->unionAll($q2); // binds to 'third'

var_dump($q->toSql());
var_dump($q->getBindings());
```

When this is run, this is the query and bind array that Fluent (in Laravel 4.2) generates:

```
(select * from `x` inner join `y` on `y`.`id` = ?)
union all
(select * from `c` where `d` = ?)
union all
(select * from `e` inner join `f` on `f`.`id` = ?)

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "third"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "second"
}
```

Assuming the bind variables are matched in order, from start to finish, the bind variables for the second and third queries are the wrong way around, e.g. `(select * from`c`where`d`= 'f1')` which should be `(select * from`c`where`d`= 'd1')`.

It seems that the where clause of q1 gets put at the end of the bind variable array, regardless of how many additional queries are subsequently added to the union. Or maybe that is just what this simplistic example looks. Perhaps the bind variables are not supposed to be in the order I think they should be?

Laravel passes the above query and bind array straight to PDO with no further processing.

Comment: You need to set the bindings within each of your individual JOIN callbacks to get them in the right order: Eloquent bindings are a real pain, especially when you have JOINS and WHERE criteria and HAVING criteria, all with their own bindings

Comment: Fluent is putting the bindings in the right place, but is just messing up the order of the data that it binds. There is enough structure in the code above (IMO) for it to get it right, so I leaning towards a bug in Fluent here. When you say "set the bindings" do you mean NOT let fluent handle it, but just insert raw SQL where I need it? That would probably work around my issue, especially since I'm binding with fixed strings and numbers and not user input in this case.

Comment: This is just Fluent (the query builder) and not Eloquent (the ORM). I'm building complex queries from a number of parameters and running those queries directly against a remote application (a SugarCRM database).

Comment: I think I can see the problem. When merging unions, the query builder merges the bindings of the first and second query using `mergeBindings()`. This separates out the WHERE bindings of the two queries and puts them together, which then get tagged onto the end of the bindings array. This is fine without the unions, since where is only one WHERE clause in a non-union query. But merging the bindings of multiple WHERE clauses in multiple queries is bound to get them in the wrong order - it just does the wrong thing.

Comment: My current workaround is to execute each query in the union as separate queries, then merge the results in PHP.

Comment: If you set the bindings for each JOIN within its own callback, then the values will be in the right order

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm unclear what you mean. From what I can see, Laravel is taking the correctly-ordered bindings from each query, and merging them together, when it should not merge them. What can I do within a query to stop it doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question is "yes". Fluent is mixing the bind variables up between UNION queries, so the final bind variable array is in the wrong order.

The Laravel query builder keeps its bind variables for each section of a query in an array:

```
// Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
protected $bindings = array(
    'select' => [],
    'join'   => [],
    'where'  => [],
    'having' => [],
    'order'  => [],
);
```

That way you can build up the query in any order you like - SELECT first, WHERE first, or mix it up a little. That is great for a single query.

What Laravel then does, when building unions, is to merge together these arrays from each query in the union. That is where the bind variables get mixed up. Instead it should parse out the bind variable array for each query, into single (linear) arrays, and then concatenate these arrays in the order that it concatenates the union queries.

I have raised this as a bug. I can't see an easy fix, so have used a workaround: run each query separately, then merge the results together in PHP, rather than expecting the database to merge the results in the union query. Other solutions such as joining the query SQL and bindings together manually, and passing them direct to PDO would work, but I'm trying not to rewrite the logic within Laravel.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5833

My advice is not to use unions in Laravel 4.2, at least. If none of your queries have any bind variables, then you may be able to use it. However, do be aware that the query builder will use bind variables for any string, number, date, number or array that you pass into any part of a query.

Comment: I'll set this as the answer, as there is nothing further to answer here.